# Is it possible to add a Button to a Wagtail Settings page?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am trying to customize a settings page so it has a button that I will assign to a certain action. (Let's assume for now I just want to log something into the console).

Ideally it would be of something like this:

```
@register_setting
class ActionTriggeringSetting(BaseSetting):
    button = models.ButtonField(
        action=myLoggingFunc,
        help_text='Click here to log "Hello World" to the console'
    )
```

I tried looking into the [site settings](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.10.1/reference/contrib/settings.html#using-the-settings) but found nothing really helpful there.

Does anybody know if something of the sort exists?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on where in the admin UI you want you button to be, there is a way using the `register-admin-menu-item` or `register-settings-menu-item` Wagtail hook

See: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.10.1/reference/hooks.html#register-admin-menu-item

and

https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.10.1/reference/hooks.html#register-settings-menu-item

The approaches above will add a button to the Wagtail Admin menu or the settings submenu, respectively. Clicking on the button will trigger a custom view that you also need to add - this is also loosely covered in the linked docs.